# using varargs and Maps

Tags: java

I want to add an object to a map but it gives an error. Maybe I have to use lists but there is getname() method so I used map. I have to check if it has a duplicate value and throw an exception if it is found

```
public class HandleApplications {

    Map<String,Name> names = new HashMap<>();

    public void addNames(String... names) throws Exception{
        Name c = new Name(names);

        if(names.containsValue(names)){
            throw new ApplicationException();
        }
         names.put(names,c) //this line gives error
    }

    public Name getName(String name) {
        return names.get(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Why are you pasting code that does not even compile?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to achieve, but you should note that you have two variables called `names`, and they have different types.

Comment: Also, `String... names` is not the same as `String names`. It looks like you treat the local `names` variable as if it's a single String.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is -

```
public void addNames(String... names) throws Exception {
    for (String s : names) {
        Name c = new Name(s);
        this.names.put(s, c);
    }
}
```

Consider changing variable names. As variable names were same, I had use this.names to refer the map.